# DataGridView design mode settings don't work after changing DataSource property

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a Win Form App, in one of it's forms I've put a `TextBox` for search and a `DataGridView` to show the results. In the grid, I've set some settings in design mode (hiding some columns and putting header text for columns). Then there is a method to fill the grid like this:(at first, it searches in the `PrsCode` and if nothing found, searches in the last name of personnel and if no matches found in both mentioned fields, it's desired to show a blank grid)

```
public void FillGrid1(bool IsSearching = false)
    {
        if (IsSearching && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TxbSearch.Text.Trim()))
        {
            var prsCode = from p in db.Prs
                          join pd in db.PDPs on p.ID equals pd.PrsID
                          where p.PrsCode.StartsWith(TxbSearch.Text.Trim())
                          select p;
            var prsLname = from p in db.Prs
                           join pd in db.PDPs on p.ID equals pd.PrsID
                           where p.Lname.Contains(TxbSearch.Text.Trim())
                           select p;
            if (prsCode.Count() > 0)
            {
                DG_PDP.DataSource = from p in db.Prs
                                    join pd in db.PDPs on p.ID equals pd.PrsID
                                    where p.PrsCode.StartsWith(TxbSearch.Text.Trim())
                                    select p;
            }
            else if (prsLname.Count() > 0)
            {
                DG_PDP.DataSource = from p in db.Prs
                                    join pd in db.PDPs on p.ID equals pd.PrsID
                                    where p.Lname.Contains(TxbSearch.Text.Trim())
                                    select p;
            }
            else
            {
                DG_PDP.DataSource = null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DG_PDP.DataSource = from p in db.Prs
               join pd in db.PDPs on p.ID equals pd.PrsID
               select p;
        }
```

In the TextChanged event of Text Box, I've wrote as below:

```
FillGrid1(true);
```

When typing and found a match, it works well. When no match found, it shows a blank grid which is fine. But, after pressing BackSpace and cleaning the `TextBox` to retype a string, if again a match is found and grid shows data, whole settings like columns visibility and header text which had been set by design mode doesn't work, like it was never been done. If I comment the else block

```
else
{
    DG_PDP.DataSource = null;
}
```

the problem of settings is solved, but the last goal of my search hasn't been reached:

> if no matches found in both mentioned fields, it's desired to show a blank grid

Comment: When you hit backspace and delete everything, in time textbox is empty, does `if (IsSearching && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TxbSearch.Text.Trim()))` passes or it blocks it?

Comment: Let me test and tell you, please... but before testing, I think it blocks it, because, as I mentioned before, the problem triggers with this; DG_PDP.DataSource = null;

Comment: I put two break points, first after !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TxbSearch.Text.Trim())) and second on line DG_PDP.DataSource = null, when pressing backspace deletes everything, just the second break point hits, it shows !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TxbSearch.Text.Trim())) blocks I think, do you agree?

Comment: Yap that is what i suspected. Instead of `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TxbSearch.Text.Trim())` use `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TxbSearch.Text)`

Comment: Thanks, but would please explain more what is the relationship between this string method and those settings set by design mode?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, because of the "new" keyword after "select" in the LINQ query, the datagridview.datasource must have the same fields as defined in new block of the query even if the query presents null. It might have been considered a humorous solution, but since in my DB, PrsID begins from 1, instead of "DG_PDP.DataSource = null" I put 0 in "where" clause of same query as other if clauses which of course returns nothing. This way the settings set by design mode haven't corrupted. Something like below:

```
public void FillGrid1(bool IsSearching = false)
{
if (IsSearching && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TxbSearch.Text.Trim()))
{
    var prsCode = from p in db.Prs
                  join pd in db.PDPs on p.ID equals pd.PrsID
                  where p.PrsCode.StartsWith(TxbSearch.Text.Trim())
                  select p;
    var prsLname = from p in db.Prs
                   join pd in db.PDPs on p.ID equals pd.PrsID
                   where p.Lname.Contains(TxbSearch.Text.Trim())
                   select p;
    if (prsCode.Count() > 0)
    {
        DG_PDP.DataSource = from p in db.Prs
                            join pd in db.PDPs on p.ID equals pd.PrsID
                            where p.PrsCode.StartsWith(TxbSearch.Text.Trim())
                            select p;
    }
    else if (prsLname.Count() > 0)
    {
        DG_PDP.DataSource = from p in db.Prs
                            join pd in db.PDPs on p.ID equals pd.PrsID
                            where p.Lname.Contains(TxbSearch.Text.Trim())
                            select p;
    }
    else// it means no match has been found
    {
        //DG_PDP.DataSource = null;
        DG_PDP.DataSource = from p in db.Prs
                            join pd in db.PDPs on p.ID equals pd.PrsID
                            where p.id==0 // I know that there is no such an ID
                            select p;
    }
}
else
{
    DG_PDP.DataSource = from p in db.Prs
                        join pd in db.PDPs on p.ID equals pd.PrsID
                        join ep in db.ExecutivePosts on pd.ExePID equals ep.ID
                        join pr in db.PDP_Priorities on pd.PriorityID equals pr.ID
                        join ps in db.PDP_Satisfactions on pd.SatisfactionID equals ps.ID
                        join s in db.SubCrts on pd.SubCrtID equals s.ID
                        select p;
}
```